# EEA family permit visa application (Accommodation)

Tags: uk, proof-of-accommodation

I’m an Irish citizen and planning to get my husband join me in UK.
I live in my grandmother's house. She will sponsor myself and my husband in her accommodation. She has been asked to provide a cover letter.

But on the application form, they asked us to state the main address and contact details of where my husband will be staying at.
Should we put my name as a contact details or my grandmother's?